# Recognizing a sub-rule of a bison grammar

Tags: parsing, bison, yacc

Is there a way to have a single grammar file create two parsers, each recognizing different rules in the grammar? As an example, let's say I have a grammar like this:

```
declaration : DEF NAME IS type
type : NAME | type ARROW NAME
```

I would like to have one `yyparse` function that recognizes declarations, and another that recognizes types. My grammar is much more complex than this simple one (if you're interested in the actual thing I'm doing, I want a function to recognize `prog` and another function to recognize `top_type_expr` in [this grammar](http://git.haldean.org/ubik/blob/master/libubik/codegen/grammar.y)) but the basic principle is that I want a shared set of rules, with functions to recognize different top-level grammar rules.

Bonus points if the solution works with pure push parsers!

Comment: With a push parser, the solution outlined in my answer to the duplicate question can be simplified considerably, since you can just start the parse by feeding `yyparse` the appropriate pseudo-token. If you insist, I can actually provide an answer to your slight variant from the duplicate.

Comment: Oh damn, that's tricky as hell. Thanks for the tip!